# Android: unable to retrieve selected Item from Spinner

Tags: android, list, menu, sms

In my application I'm try to send `received inbox sms's` details - sender's address, receive time as a new message using `Sms Manager to send message`. Also I'm providing different format so that these details will be set according to format. Multiple messages are selected using checkboxes. I'm providing these format in `application menu as setting menuItem` The problem is the `sent` message doesn't displaying `Sender's No`.

In Main Activity:

```
String  address="",date="",body="", phoneNo;
Spinner fSpinner,phSpinner;
```

When open the setting in menu a `alert dialog` pops up that contain two spinners - fSpinner for body format and phSpinner for phone number.

```
case R.id.action_settings:

    AlertDialog.Builder rdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    rdialog.setTitle("Select Format");
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
    alertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rptsetting,null);

    final Spinner fSpinner = (Spinner)alertView.findViewById(R.id.fSpinner);
    String providers[] ={"Address","Time"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,providers);
    fSpinner.setAdapter(adp);
    fSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> aparent, View arg1,
                int pos, long arg3) {

            String selectedItem = aparent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if(selectedItem.equals("Address")){
                body = "Sender's Address -"+address+", Message Body -"+reltxt.getText().toString();  
            }

            else if(selectedItem.equals("Time")){
                    body = "Message Time -"+time.get(i)+", Message Body -"+reltxt.getText().toString();
            }}

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> aparent) {
        }
    });

    final Spinner phSpinner = (Spinner)alertView.findViewById(R.id.phSpinner);

    String number[] ={"1234","2222","0000"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adp1 = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,number);
    phSpinner.setAdapter(adp1);
    phSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> phParent, View item,
                int post, long arg3) {
            String phNo = phParent.getSelectedItem().toString();
            phlabel = phParent.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if(phNo.equals("1234")){
                phoneNo = "1234";
            }
            else if(phNo.equals("2222")){
                phoneNo="2222";
            }
            else if(phNo.equals("0000")){
                phoneNo="0000";
            }}

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> phParent) {
        }
    });
    rdialog.setView(alertView);
    rdialog.setNeutralButton("SUBMIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();   
            }
        });

    AlertDialog rdialog1 = rdialog.create();
    rdialog1.show();
```

The checked message's will be stored in array `list`. and the Sms Manager will send details of these selected messages. phoneNo as selected by phSpinner and body as selected using fSpinner.

```
if(list.size()>0){
     for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
     {
         if(list.get(i).isSelected())
         {
             if(address.equals(""))
                 address =list.get(i).getAddress();
             else
                 address =list.get(i).getAddress();
             try 
             {
                 SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
                 smsMgr.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, body, null, null);
             }
             catch (Exception e) 
             {
                 Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage()+"!\n"+"SMS failed, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
String selectedItem = fSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Instead of this..

```
String selectedItem = aparent.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

and also.

```
String phNo = phSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
phlabel = phSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Instead of

```
String phNo = phParent.getSelectedItem().toString();
phlabel = phParent.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: still its unable to get `Sender's address`

Comment: @Androidbeginner where your getting `Sender's address`

Comment: to get `Sender's address` I'm using `if(address.equals(""))                  address =list.get(i).getAddress();              else                  address =list.get(i).getAddress();` in `sendSms ()` and the code is above for that.